# What is the syntactic function of "called a typedef" in the sentence "C provides a facility called a typedef"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

What is the syntactic function of the non-finite clause ***"called a typedef"*** in the sentence ***"C provides a facility called a typedef."***?

Comment: For a minute, I thought this was a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a subordinate (or dependent) clause. It is a little difficult to identify since the words *that is* have been omitted:

> C provides a facility **that is** called a typedef.

With the relative pronoun *that* included, the rest of the sentence is easier to identify as a subordinate clause.

[Wikipedia: Dependant clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause)

Comment: Linguists refer to this process as "whiz deletion" ('whiz' stands for 'which is').

Comment: @ColinFine I was wondering what the precise term was. I looked up *elide*, but that didn't seem to fit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Finally, I have found a similar structure in my prefered grammar reference, which calls such structures "reduced relative clauses", too.

Comment: @Sinushyperbolikus I wouldn't accept answers straight away. Give it 24 hours. You may get a better (and more precise) answer. I am no expert. Accepting answers too soon may discourage other users from posting answers.

Comment: Such a construction can also be analyzed as a participial phrase, here modifying _facility_.

Comment: There are over 100 hits in a search for 'reduced relative clause' on ELU. Other hits for 'whiz deletion'.